# abstract Algebra for polynom

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove: Any irreducible normalized polynomial $p\in \Bbb{R}[X]$
is either linear (i.e. $\deg(p) = 1$) or square (i.e. $\deg(p) = 2$). In the linear case it has the shape $(X - a)$  for $a \in \Bbb{R}$, in the square case it has the shape
$(X - a)^{2} +  b$ with $a ,b \in \Bbb{R}$ and $b > 0$. Conversely, all polynomials of the specified
shapes are irreducible.

Comment: Do you know that the irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb C[X]$ are all linear?

Comment: no, I don't know that